# How to store a set of matrices with 2 attributes in a file in python

Tags: python, matrix

I have written a piece of code that generates a set of matrices and vectors, solves them with 2 different methods, and then plots the solve times of each method. Each matrix has a magnitude n, and a value 'm' which denotes which number matrix of size n in the set(so if I have 2 matrices of size n and I generate another, its 'm' value would be 3). Each matrix is constructed, solved, the solve time is stored, and then the matrices are destroyed, 1 by 1.

My problem is that each time I want to view the scatter plot of data, I would have to generate and solve each of the systems all over again which takes a lot of time. What would be the best way of saving this set of matrices into a file so that I can access each matrix individually by its magnitude and 'm' value?

Comment: You could [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/pickle.html) them, or use a [json](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/json.html)-file?

Comment: I will look into that, thank you.